# How to do voice morphing to a phone call on android?

Tags: android, voice

I'm develop an android application which needs to change the callers voice to chipmunk voice in real time processing. ie.like Whenever someone calls me, i want to hear their voice in chipmunk voice. I dont find any control or any api to do that in android. Also i dont know how to stop the voice from native phone receiver. Is this feature possible in android? Please give me show ideas to do the same.

Comment: Why isn't this a real question? IMO It is not _that_ vague or _overly_ broad.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't**, unless you mean VOIP calls implemented outside of the framework rather than mobile network calls.

Android does not provide access to the in-call audio.  On (many? all?) present devices that's thought to actually be a hardware limitation or at least buried in vendor-proprietary code for the radio processor, and so not alterable from the android/linux side even if you root, install a customized build, etc.