# Voice Morphing to callers voice

Tags: android, voice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do voice morphing to a phone call on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026931/how-to-do-voice-morphing-to-a-phone-call-on-android)

I want to process and change the callers voice to chipmunk voice in real time. I don't find the way to stop the voice from native phone call receiver. Is there any way to stop the voice played from native phone call receiver?

PS: I have posted the same question again as my previous question was closed with reason "Vague and overly broad". Now i made some corrections to be more specific. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Did you read the only answer to that closed question?

Comment: that's not how it works. Go back and edit your previous question if you think you can make it better. It'll get reopen if the community changes its mind.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible. Android applications do not have access to the in-call audio, let alone have the ability to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried this feature, but as per the API's available in android , its not possible to implement,and there is no hardware suppor for this. As per knowledge there is hardware support provided by Android framework , to go with this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This thing is not possible in real time. We have one feature like this in some handsets but they have implementing it through hardware support. As android allows us to interact with the hardware very less and also sound API's are not available to do this feature. When it comes to spoof app they have implementing it through 3rd party vendor and we have to pay for that every minute we use and it works only in USA not the other part of the world as the 3rd party vendor belongs to U